# is it possible to remove the author tab from maven-changelog-plugin

Tags: maven, report, changelog

I am currently generating a few changelog reports for my project and I am wondering if it is possible to remove the author column from the report. Ive tried maping the svn ids to the same string xxxxxx but that seem not to work. anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you like to do so? Just leaving it empty is not an option?

Comment: it picks up from the SCM system, is it possible to make it empty?

Comment: Not that i know. I would suggest to create ticket to enhance the functionality.